# LARAVEL - ERROR AL VALIDAR FICHEROS CSS Y JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, laravel, archivo

tengo un formulario en el que quiero permitir que se puedan subir archivos .html, .css y .js.

```html
<div class="form-group row">{{-- ARCHIVOS --}}

  <label for="files" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Archivos</label>

  <div class="col-md-auto">
      <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple accept=".html,.css,.js" id="files"
      class="form-control-file @error('files') is-invalid @enderror">
      @error('files')
        <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
      @enderror
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Al momento de validar los ficheros, solo valida correctamente los .html. He probado a usar tanto la regla mimes como la de mimetypes.

```
$rules = [
  "files" => "required|array",
  "files.*" => "mimes:html,css,js",
  "files.*" => "mimetypes:text/html,text/css,application/javascript"
];
$messages = [
  "files.required" => "Es obligatorio subir algún archivo",
  "files.*.mimes" => "NOP",
  "files.*.mimetypes" => "NOP"
];
$this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
print_r($request->files);
```

He probado a quitarle la restricción y me ha mostrado que el mimetype de los js es text/javascript, aunque en el fichero de configuración de nginx está el que he usado antes, pero tampoco me ha funcionado. He probado las reglas con imágenes y no hay problema, no sé que puedo estar haciendo mal.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno y a la hora de mostrar el mensaje de error solo me muestra los del array no los de cada fichero.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rules = [
      "files.*" => "required|mimes:text/html,text/css,application/javascript",
    ];
    $messages = [
      "files.*.required" => "Es obligatorio subir algún archivo",
      "files.*.mimes" => "formato de archivo no soportado"
    ];
    $this->validate($request, $rules, $messages);
    print_r($request->files);
```

Comment: prueba este codigo